# Unity c# check for an empty string always return false

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I have the following code to check if in text component attached to my gamobject contains an empty string,

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputFieldText.text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputFieldText.text) || inputFieldText.text == "" || inputFieldText.text.Trim() == string.Empty )
        {
            //Do my stuff
        }
```

as a matter of fact, using the debugger (see the image attached), I can see that the string is empty but for some reason all of the check methods that I've tried return false.
What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: It's part of an `else` statement - are you entering the earlier `if` condition? If you do the original if then you won't enter the else.

Comment: By the way, all your conditions there can be simplified into a single `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(inputFieldText.text)`...

Comment: @Chuck yes it's an else statement, but I'm not entering the early if condition which checks if the string is more than 13 characters

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace yes I know that what I tried at first, but since it wasn't working, I tried to add the other conditions

Comment: Check the length of the string you got there in the debugger. Make sure you actuall see its length property being 0. Do not rely on the visual string representation alone. `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputFieldText.text)` returning _false_ means without a doubt that the string provided by _inputFieldText.text_ is actually not empty nor made of whitespaces only. There are Unicode characters that aren't rendered visually, and if a string is made of of only such character(s), it can give the illusion to be empty despite it being not.

Comment: (An illustrative but not exhaustive example: create a string like `string s = "\u200B"; int l = s.Length;` and see in the debugger how Visual Studio presents the value of this string to you, then check its length...)

Comment: I know you THINK the check is if the length is greater than 13, but I would really encourage you to share the code that's doing the check. Maybe you're comparing against a parameter that was set incorrectly, or a string you think is initialized but isn't, or you've swapped > and <, etc. You're probably right, but that's really the only thing that makes sense to me and I'd like to double check your work <3

Comment: @Chuck the screenshot of the debugger shows that it is definitely reaching the `else if` thus it hasn't entered the `if` block ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess into the dark but you seem to be using the `TextMeshProUGUI` component of the input field (assuming this from the name `inputFieldText`).

So I assume this to be related to this https://forum.unity.com/threads/float-parse-does-not-work-in-tmpro-input-field-which-basically-means-tmpro-is-useless.718268/#post-4804799

> > Perhaps related...
> >
> > ```
> > manager.networkAddress = IPField.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text.Trim();
> > ```
> >
> > ...includes a Unicode Zero Width Space (U+200B) on the end that Trim() doesn't remove.
>
> That is correct in terms of why the float.Parse would fail. However, and more importantly, this is due to referencing the child text component instead of the parent `TMP_InputField` and its `.text` property.

=> change the type to

```
public TMP_Inputfield inputFieldText;
```

assign it again via the Inspector and try again with simply

```
...
}
else if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputFieldText.text))
{
...
```